# Downloading images from Windows Azure blob?

Tags: android, azure, azure-blob-storage

Basically I wish to store images as a blob on windows azure, each image will be linked to a different entry ina table in a database on azure and I wish to make it so my android app can lookup the image linked to that table entry and then download it the app. I've been reading the documentation but unsure on how to do this as most of it seems talk about uploading to blob rather than downloading?

Regards

Sam

Comment: Do you have any code that your trying now? .

Comment: I was asking how to do, as I wasn't unsure where to start?

Answer (score 1):

If the ACL of the container is public you can access the blob by its url:

https://accountName.blob.core.windows.net/containerName/myblobName

If you don't have your container public its a little bit more work. But the short version is that you add a few things to the header of your request ( x-ms-version ) and you can access the image.

see more examples of this on [Windows azure rest api reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dd179440)